# How to get the best model after early stopping without saving it to a file?

Tags: python, keras

If training is early stopped, the best model is saved to the file best_model.h5. But loading the model from the file takes a relatively long time. Is there a way to get the best model in another way?

For example, by creating the file in memory and reading it from memory. Or by putting each model for each epoch into a list and getting the best model from the list by using EarlyStopping.stopped_epoch to access the corresponding list item.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 3))/100, columns=['x_1', 'x_2','y'])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['x_1', 'x_2']], df[['y']], test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2),
             ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear', input_dim=2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam',metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

model = load_model('best_model.h5')

print(model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=32))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the model's current state at some point because further training will change this state.

If you are not going to save (the easiest option with `ModelCheckpoint`), then you need a custom callback that performs a `stored_weights = model.get_weights()`.

### Option 1

You can try to use `save_weights_only=True` in the `ModelCheckpoint` and later, with the same model use `model.load_weights(path)`. This will not create a new model, only load the weights.

### Option 2

If even so you think it's too slow, then you can create your own callback and use RAM to store the weights:

```
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

bestLoss = 1000000000000000000
bestWeights = None

def storeWeights(e, logs):
    if logs['val_loss'] < bestLoss:
        bestLoss = logs['val_loss']
        bestWeights = model.get_weights()

callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2), 
             LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=storeWeights)]

#train here
model.fit...........................
#finished train

model.set_weights(bestWeights)
```